# Source Control - Discard all changes deleted my xcworkspace and I can't fix it

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode5

I was trying to undo changes on my project to the last committed Source Control state, however when I pressed 'Discard all changes' weird behaviour happened.

The first time some of the files reverted whilst others didn't. So I pressed the button again and a blurb popped up saying something about needed to re-save the 'xcworkspace'. I pressed okay and half my files disappeared from the xcode file list on the left, really random files that hadn't been edited at all. So I decided to press revert again to see if I could get back to my original state, and now all my files have disappeared from the xcworkspace. So my screen now looks like this:

[image]

I have tried restoring the files from my trash (as this is where random ones have appeared) but the workspace is never restored. I use MapBox so I have 2 projects building in to 1 workspace, but the podfile will now not install.

Can anyone give me advice on how to get this back to it's original state as I have been trying for a few hours but can't find any information.

Comment: Have you tried restoring to a known state with an external client?

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue lies mainly with my repository. I branched off the code and I think this is causing only parts of the repository to be picked up by xcode, hence why random files I hadn't touched disappeared. I have just remade my project, taken a couple of days but it's given me a chance to sort the repository too. 
Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I just had this happen to me too.  I also selected Discard All Changes and half my project ended up in the trash. Some entitlements files, the scheme files, some icon files and who know what else.  This is seriously annoying, so much for source code management with Xcode!

Comment: I had the same thing happen just now. Xcode 6.3. My workspace file went into the trash and I got a warning which then shutdown my Xcode. Not sure what is going on. In the end I was able to rerun 'pod install' and everything (seems to be) back to normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I felt horrible when I did this. I really thought I had to rebuild everything over again. Luckily, it was easy to repair.

Xcode removed all the "non-essential" files. This includes your Podfile (and if applicable, GoogleService-Info.plist).

**To Repair:**

1. Go to Terminal and create a Podfile in your project folder `$ pod init`
2. Update your Podfile with the pods you need
3. Run `$ pod install`

(4.) To re-generate the GoogleService-Info.plist file, go to your console.firebase.google.com > Settings > Project Settings > Download the latest config file for the appropriate project iOS app and save to your local project folder. Your workspace should recognize the file in the Project Navigator list.

Once you open your workspace, select new Scheme and everything should be back to normal.

**To avoid future regressions:**

Go to Terminal

> git add -A

to add the pod files, then

> git commit -m "Save pod files"

to save pod files. I believe git from Xcode ignores the pod and scheme files.

Comment: Another option is just adding the podfile and GoogleService-Info.plist instead of all of the pod files - then you can just `pod install` to restore your workspace